# accessing a linkbutton inside the radgrid giving error

Tags: asp.net, telerik, radgrid

I am trying to access radgrid control(linkbutton) from javascript. I am getting a null defined error. Below is my javascript and radgrid. radgrid is inside the radpanel and also the code behind from where I am invoking the javascript.

```
<script>
 function warningMessage(rowIndex) {

            debugger;
            var dataItems = $find('<%= RadPanelBar1.Items[0].Items[0].FindControl("RadGrid_MCLIDPicker").ClientID %>').get_masterTableView().get_dataItems();

        -- getting null error in the above line    
            }

    </script>
```

And my radgrid is below

```
 <telerik:RadPanelBar ID="RadPanelBar1" runat="server" Width="1500px" BackColor="#E6E6E6"
    ExpandMode="MultipleExpandedItems">
    <Items>
        <telerik:RadPanelItem runat="server" Text="ID Picker" Expanded="true">
            <Items>
                <telerik:RadPanelItem Text="" Expanded="true">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <table>


                            <tr>
                                <td>
                                    <telerik:RadGrid ID="RadGrid_IDPicker" AllowSorting="false"  AllowPaging="false"
                                        runat="server" GridLines="None"  Width="1500px" Visible="false">
                                        <MasterTableView RetrieveAllDataFields="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="ID" EnableViewState="true" ClientDataKeyNames="ID"  >
                                            <Columns>
                                                <telerik:GridTemplateColumn UniqueName="TemplateLinkColumn" AllowFiltering="false"
                                                    HeaderText="ID">
                                                    <ItemTemplate>

                                                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1"  runat="server"  OnClick="ID_Link_Click" Text='<%#Bind("ID") %>'></asp:LinkButton>
                                                    </ItemTemplate>
                                                </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>

                                            </Columns>
                                        </MasterTableView>
                                        <PagerStyle Mode="NextPrevAndNumeric" />
                                    </telerik:RadGrid>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <telerik:RadAjaxManager ID="RadAjaxManager1" runat="server">
                            <AjaxSettings>
                                <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="radBtn_Search">
                                    <UpdatedControls>
                                        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid_IDPicker" LoadingPanelID="LoadingPanel1" />
                                    </UpdatedControls>
                                </telerik:AjaxSetting>

                                <telerik:AjaxSetting AjaxControlID="ID_Link">
                                    <UpdatedControls>
                                        <telerik:AjaxUpdatedControl ControlID="RadGrid_IDPicker" LoadingPanelID="LoadingPanel1" />
                                    </UpdatedControls>
                                </telerik:AjaxSetting>
                            </AjaxSettings>
                        </telerik:RadAjaxManager>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </telerik:RadPanelItem>
            </Items>
        </telerik:RadPanelItem>
    </Items>     
</telerik:RadPanelBar>
```

My code behind is

```
  protected void ID_Link_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         try
         {

           LinkButton btn = (LinkButton)sender;
             GridDataItem row = (GridDataItem)btn.NamingContainer;
             ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "message", string.Format("warningMessage('{0}');", row.ItemIndex), true);


}
catch()
{
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to get the reference of the radpaelbar and this is how I did it

```
   var dataItems = $find('<%= RadPanelBar1.Items[0].Items[0].FindControl     ("RadGrid_IDPicker").ClientID %>').get_masterTableView().get_dataItems();
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that you need to get a reference to the PanelBar before you can get a reference to the RadGrid. Try doing simply this:

```
var dataItems = 
$find('<%=RadGrid_IDPicker.ClientID%>').get_masterTableView().get_dataItems();
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Icarus -- I don't think that you need to get a reference to the PanelBar to access the RadGrid. If you need to access that linkbutton, you can loop through the dataItems that you get. You can try to do the following:

```
var grid = $find("<%= RadGrid_IDPicker.ClientID %>");
var tbl = grid.get_masterTableView();
for (var i=0; i < tbl.get_dataItems().length; i++)
     var gridItemElem = tbl.get_dataItems()[i].findElement("LinkButton1");
```